# Unique solution of $A^3 = B$, where $A$, $B$ is a diagonal matrix given below.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Show that $A^3 = B$ has exactly one REAL solution (which is easy to find), where:
$$B = 
\begin{bmatrix}8& 0& 0\\
0& -1& 0\\
0& 0 &27\end{bmatrix}$$

Finding the solution is really easy. But how can we show that it's the only solution ?
I know that the power of a diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix, but is the opposite: the nth root of a diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix, also true ? And if so, how to prove it ?

Comment: It is not true if you allow complex matrices. The question shold make clear what kind of matrices are considered.

Comment: Also, it is not in general true that any square root of a diagonal matrix must be diagonal; for instance, a rotation by a quarter turn in a plane defined by two coordinate axes has as square a diagonal matrix, but it is not itself diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for helping and answering the second question. The main question ask for real solution.

Answer (score 3):

The main points about this situation are that (1) the matrix $B$ is diagonalisable over the real numbers (it is even diagonal), and (2) its eigenspaces all have dimension$~1$ (because the diagonal entries are all distinct); also relevant is of course that cube roots of *scalars* always uniquely exist over the real numbers.

If $A$ is such that $A^3=B$, then clearly $A$ and $B$ must commute. Now if $v$ any eigenvector for $B$, then $Av$ is also an eigenvector for $B$, for the same eigenvalue: say $Bv=\lambda v$ then $B(Av)=A(Bv)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda(Av)$. But by property (2) above, this means $Av$ is a scalar multiple of $v$, in other words $v$ is also an eigenvector for$~A$. Then any basis of eigenvectors for$~B$ is also a basis of eigenvectors for$~A$, and $A$ will be diagonal when expressed on such a basis. In the example, the standard basis is such a basis of eigenvectors, in other words $A$ must, just like$~B$, be a diagonal matrix. As you already saw, it can only be the matrix obtained by taking cube roots of each of the diagonal entries of$~B$.

Answer (score 1):

The result follows from a direct computation using Buchberger's algorithm as follows. Write $A=(a_{ij})$ with $9$ parameters as entries. The Buchberger's algorithm immediately gives the following: the diagonal elements $a_{ii}$ have to satisfy one of the following equations:
$$
(a_{11},a_{22},a_{33})=(2,-1,3),
$$
or
$$
a_{11}^2 + 2a_{11} + 4=0,
$$
or
$$
a_{22}^2 - a_{22} + 1=0,
$$
or

$$
a_{33}^2 + 3a_{33} + 9=0.
$$
The last three equations do not have real solutions. Then we easily see that $A={\rm diag}(2,-1,3)$ is the only real solution.

Edit: In this question

[$A$ is a symmetric real matrix. Show that there is $B$ such that $B^3=A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618986/a-is-a-symmetric-real-matrix-show-that-there-is-b-such-that-b3-a?rq=1)

the claim is proved, too, since our matrix here is indeed symmetric.

Comment: Could you explain more about the Buchberger's algorithm ? Because I am studying pretty basic linear algebra and concepts, so a simple solution without needing too much knowledge/methods is expected and would be better. Thank you in advance

Comment: For the algorithm see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm). It is a standard tool in computer algebra. Of course, one can argue whether or not one should use an algorithm, like for computing a determinant. However, you can do without it, using substitution and manipulating the polynomial equations. The same can be done computing a determinant by hand, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$Q = 
\begin{bmatrix}2& 0& 0\\
0& -1& 0\\
0& 0 &3\end{bmatrix}$$

We are given $$0=A^3-Q^3=(A-Q)(A^2+AQ+Q^2)=(A-Q)(A-\alpha Q)(A-\overline{\alpha}Q)$$ where $\alpha = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}} = -\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$

The solutions are

$$\begin{align} A &=Q, &(\textrm{real})\phantom{000}\\
A &= \alpha Q,  &(\textrm{complex})\\
A &= \overline{\alpha}Q,  &(\textrm{complex}) \end{align}$$

Notice $\{1, \alpha, \overline{\alpha} \}$ are the three cube roots of one.

**UPDATE**

These are not the only solutions.  We could have taken $Q$ to be any of

$$Q = 
\begin{bmatrix} \mp 2& 0& 0\\
0& -1& 0\\
0& 0 &\mp 3\end{bmatrix}$$,

so it looks like there are $(4)\cdot (3) = 12$ solutions, not only $3$.

To address the last part of the question:

If $A^n = \Lambda$,  Let $Q$ be an  $n^\textrm{th}$ root of $\Lambda$ and $\alpha$ an $n^\textrm{th}$ root of unity.  Then  $A \in \{  Q, \alpha Q , \dots, \alpha^{n-1} Q \}$, are solutions.  As Marc pointed out, the solutions need not be diagonal, for example, a rotation matrix that rotates by an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Your factorization requires that $AQ=QA$, which is not clear to me.  However, if you have this, then standard results give that $A$ and $Q$ are simultaneously diagonalizable and the problem reduces to 3 one dimensional problems.

Comment: $A=\alpha^k Q$, so they commute.

Comment: No, you came to that conclusion AFTER implicitly assuming they commute. But even with them commuting, there are 9 solutions if you don’t restrict to real matrices. Each of the entries can be multiplied by different powers of $\alpha$ independent of each other.

Comment: @Aaron, yes, you make some great points!  I"ll have to look at it again when I have some time.  Perhaps there are nine, perhaps more.  There was also the possibility of including rotation matrices as well.

Comment: About your point assuming they commute and then using that after!  Yes, true for these but this "procedure" will miss those solutions that do not commute.  Again, quick comments here.  Thank you for providing direction on what to think about to make this more rigorous and complete.